# Bevy version 0.10.0: How to fix 'WindowDescriptor not found in this scope' error?

Tags: rust, struct, window, descriptor, bevy

## Problems with Bevy version 0.10.0 WindowDescriptor struct

I saw this tutorial:[Bevy Game Engine Tutorial - Window and First Sprite (Ep1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnUzWuaMzuM) and I tried to do the same thing, but my Bevy is in version 0.10.0, and this structure `WindowDescriptor` is not working, I've tried to do it in other ways seen here on Stack OverFlow but without success with that so far!

My code is like this:

```
use bevy::prelude::*;

pub const CLEAR: Color = Color::rgb(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

fn main() {
    App::new()
    .insert_resource(ClearColor(CLEAR))
    .insert_resource(WindowDescriptor {
            title: "Bevy Demo".to_string(),
            width: 1600.0,
            height: 900.0,
            vsync: true,
            resizable: true,
            ..Default::default()
    })
    .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
    .run();
}
```

My Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "test-bevy-game"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[profile.dev]
opt-level = 1

[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3

[dependencies]
bevy = { version = "0.10.1", features = ["dynamic_linking"] }
```

And the debug error is this:

```
error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `WindowDescriptor` in this scope
 --> src\main.rs:8:22
  |
8 |     .insert_resource(WindowDescriptor {
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0422`.
error: could not compile `test-bevy-game` due to previous error
```

I just don't want the compiler to give me any errors about this, I hope I can at least add the ecs vsync, width, height, title statically in my code, I want to know if bevy in version 0.10.0 need to change the version to an older one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Windowdescriptor in Bevy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74898186/how-to-use-windowdescriptor-in-bevy)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to see how things are done in various versions of Bevy (since development is still pretty rapid) is to look through their extensive set of [examples](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/tree/v0.10.1/examples). The one for [window settings](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/v0.10.1/examples/window/window_settings.rs) can give us the basics:

```
App::new()
    .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(WindowPlugin {
        primary_window: Some(Window {
            title: "I am a window!".into(),
            resolution: (500., 300.).into(),
            present_mode: PresentMode::AutoVsync,
            ..default()
        }),
        ..default()
    }))
```

So you can specify the details for the window by creating a [`Window`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/window/struct.Window.html) and provide it as the `primary_window` of the [`WindowPlugin`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/window/struct.WindowPlugin.html) when setting up your app. You would then access the `Window` later through a `Query` if you need to.